# Expected value of function of multiple variables

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be continuous i.i.d. r.v.'s and let $Y=g(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ where $g$ is sufficiently smooth. The particular problem I want to use this for has $g(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=\sqrt{X_1 ^2 +\cdots+ X_n ^2}$ so all the properties of that function can be assumed. I want to prove $$E[Y]=\int _{D} g(x_1,\ldots,x_n) f_{X_1,\ldots,X_n}(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \, dx_1 \cdots dx_n.$$

where $D = \{ (x_1,\ldots,x_n): x_i \in X_i(\Omega) \quad\forall i =1,\dots,n\}$

But I don't see how to start, even in the simple case of $n=2$, and I can't seem to find a proof. It would be great if someone could point me to some info on this.

Comment: As the $X_i$'s are i.i.d then $ E[Y]= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}...\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x_1,...,x_n)$f(x_1)... f(x_n)dx_1...dx_n $.

Comment: Why? I have trouble seeing why $f_Y (y) = f_{X_1,...,X_n}(x_1,...,x_n)$

Comment: Let $X$ be a continuous r.v. with prob. distribution $f(x)$ and $g$ be a function of $X$. Then $E[g(X)]=\int_{\infty}^{\infty}g(x)f(x)dx$. All you need is to consider the multivariate case.

Comment: Alright, this makes sense, but I still don't really understand how to get that result, from the definition, even for the univariate case. I'll have a look tomorrow because I'm too tired to think right now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you look at the univariate case, then  your domain $D$ is nothing but the image of $X$, i.e. the whole real line. This is true also in the multivariate case: the formula you write is then the one in my comment above. If you request it, I move all these considerations to an answer.